# Jquery Drag and Drop with multiple Drop placeholders and reset option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, xhtml

im trying to develop a game using jquery drag and drop and need help on it. The problem i am facing is that there are 4 drop location and about 25 dragable elements. Each drop location can have only one draggable element and if i try to drop another element the location should be swapped and previously dropped element will get the initial location of newly dragged element.

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  containment: ".dropable",
  revert: "invalid",
  appendTo: '.dropable',
  start: function (evt, ui) {
    if (!ui.helper.data("originalPosition")) {
        ui.helper.data("originalPosition", ui.originalPosition)
    }
}
});
$(".debit_option").droppable({
  greedy: true,
  accept: '.drag',
  over: function () {
    $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('hoverClass')
},
  out: function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hoverClass').addClass('out')
},
  drop: function (event, ui) {}
});
$(".credit_option").droppable({
 over: function () {
  $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('hoverClass')
 },
 out: function () {
  $(this).removeClass('hoverClass').addClass('out')
 },
 drop: function (event, ui) {}
 })
 });
function revertDraggable($selector) {
$selector.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($this.data('originalPosition'));
    position = $this.data('originalPosition');
    if (position) {
        $this.animate({
            left: position.left,
            top: position.top
        }, 500, function () {
            $this.data("orignalPosition", null)
        })
    }
})
}
$(".no_entry a").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   revertDraggable($(".drag"))
});
```

Comment: i cant see any questions or problems here. whats exaclty not working? if the revert thing is a problem for you notice that with the "drop" event of droppable you can get the elements inside and also the element which is ready to drop. there should be no problem to switch them.

Comment: I am unable to understand how i get the element which is being dropped and then replace the already droped element with the location of new element. i need some help in the drop event handler rest of the code is working just fine. Thanks in advance